# Hibernate 5: Count value returned as java.time.Duration instead of java.lang.Long

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-5.x, hibernate-4.x

While trying to fetch Count(*) using Hibernate 5.4.17, the count value (from `nativeQuery.uniqueResult()` below) is being returned as java.time.Duration, when the same used to be returned as java.lang.Long with Hibernate 4.2.17.

Code:

```
@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
    public int getResultCount(String queryString) {
        NativeQuery nativeQuery = this.getNativeSQLQuery(queryString);
        Object countObject = nativeQuery.uniqueResult();
        if (countObject instanceof BigInteger) {
            BigInteger obj = (BigInteger)countObject;
            return obj.intValue();
        } else {
            long count = (Long)countObject;
            return (int)count;
        }
    }
```

value of queryString -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Role role inner join ( SELECT rolePriv.role_id FROM role_privilege rolePriv WHERE rolePriv.permission IN ('user:view','user:edit') GROUP BY  rolePriv.role_id HAVING COUNT(distinct rolePriv.permission) = 2 ) rolePrivResult  on role.role_id=rolePrivResult.role_id where role.type = 0
```

Can someone please advise me what might be going incorrect, and where I should be looking at? I am not pasting the `nativeQuery` object value here as it is huge. Please let me if some specific field is needed or should be looked into.

Thanks!

Comment: Which database are you using ?

Comment: @OsamaAbdulRehman We are MySQL.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but are you sure it is a ```java.time.Duration```you get? Have you tried to print out ```countObject.getClass()```?

Comment: @KajHejer - Yes. Additionally, during actual run, it failed with a class cast exception at the place where I am trying to cast into Long:
java.time.Duration cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Comment: @Rohan Bhattacharya OK, thanks! Are you sure you have set the ```hibernate.dialect``` correctly (or that hibernate does it for you? Do you use a updated version of your jdbc driver?

Comment: @Rohan Bhattacharya Just to simplify the problem you cound try to use ```SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Role``` as your query to debug.

Comment: Could you debug into `org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata#getHibernateType` and see what happens there?